# Copy a file in C

Tags: c, file, copy

I try to copy a file in a new file but it doesn't work because the input is 5133KB and the output is 614byte... what's wrong? Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    FILE * input    =   fopen("input.wav", "r");
    FILE * output   =   fopen("output.wav", "w");

    char    buffer;
    int     bytesRead = 1;

    while(bytesRead=fread(&buffer,1,1,input))
    {
        fwrite(&buffer,1,1,output);
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Aside*: your program will go uncomfortably slow unless you increase the size of your buffer.

Comment: Yes, I can't imagine why you would want to read ONE BYTE AT A TIME.

Comment: The reason was that I wanted to write the simplest program I could to show better my problem..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to open the file in *binary mode* on your system. From C.2011, §7.21.5.3:

> **`rb`** open binary file for reading
>   **`wb`** truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing

So:

```
FILE * input    =   fopen("input.wav", "rb");
FILE * output   =   fopen("output.wav", "wb");
```

The reason is that on some systems, certain embedded binary characters may cause the text mode processing to believe the end of file has been encountered, even though there are actually more bytes in the file.